# Failing to inject isolated content from a Chrome Extension using React and Shadow Dom

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, shadow-dom

I'm writing a Chrome extension using React.
This extension has some content part, which injects a widget on some specific pages.
The stylesheet of the host page and the widget are completely different, therefore I don't want them to be mixing up.
To be more specific the widget uses [Semantic-UI](http://react.semantic-ui.com/) components and some of the host pages use *bootstrap*.

I found out about Shadow Dom and based on my understanding it's supposed to avoid the css [leaking out from my component and vice-versa](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom)

> Scoped CSS: CSS defined inside shadow DOM is scoped to it. Style rules don't leak out and page styles don't bleed in.

Great, it seems that it's exactly what I want.

So then I've changed my React root function to something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {Store} from 'react-chrome-redux';

import AppContainer from './components/AppContainer';
import Toolbar from './components/Toolbar';

const proxyStore = new Store({portName: 'my-extension'});

const anchor = document.createElement('div');
anchor.id = 'my-extension-anchor';
const shadowRoot = anchor.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})

const semanticUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL("styles/semantic.min.css")

document.body.appendChild(anchor)

render(
  <Provider store={proxyStore}>
      <div>
          <link id='semantic-ui' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href={semanticUrl} media='all' />
          <AppContainer>
              <Toolbar />
          </AppContainer>
      </div>
  </Provider>
  , shadowRoot);
```

The first thing I noticed is that my widget was not getting the right fonts.
After some google, I found [this post](http://robdodson.me/at-font-face-doesnt-work-in-shadow-dom/) explaining I'd to take my font-faces out from semantic-ui files and inject it on the head of the host.
Now it seems to be working, but it still sounds like a cheap workaround.

Anyway, even after this change it's not working as I expected, the CSS inside my widget is not leaking out anymore... but my widget is being affected by the current page stylesheet.
I've tried a few other modifications:

1. Using mode closed instead of open
2. Using a few React libraries, i.e: [ReactShadow](https://github.com/Wildhoney/ReactShadow)

When I inspect my element I can see it's using some stylesheets from the host page, showing something like:

> Inherited from div#my-extension-anchor body { bootstrap.min....

And my widget should be "bootstrap-free".

Did I misunderstood how Shadow DOM works? 
There's a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: I did it, It's is listed in the question among the attempts I've done.

Comment: have you used ReactShadow library?. Please post a details solution that you achieved. It would be helpful @daniefranca

Comment: I did use ReactShadwo, but unfortunately, until now I haven't found a satisfactory solution =/

Comment: Actually am running on exact problem that you are facing, I tried both the solutions above. But in my case `ReactShadow` won't work for me because it doesn't support `.less` extension style sheets. Please update me if you get a better solution :). Thanks.